# 一つの変数に入った複数の値を、1行の行列としてまとめたい

Tags: python, python3

以下のプログラムで出力された結果を1行の行列として出力したいと考えています。
`niter`であれば、`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7....19,20]`のような行列で
`rnorm`であれば、`[1.2340014751660304,0.9402715810329509...,1.0]`のような行列です。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
import math as ma

d     = 2500
x     = 2500  
area  = 100   
e     = 5e5   
f     = 0     
resid = 0     
nincr = 1      
fincr = 1.5e7  
cnorm = 1e-20  
miter = 20     

lzero = ma.sqrt(x**2 + d**2)                 
vol   = area*lzero                          
stiff = (area/lzero)*e*(x/lzero)*(x/lzero)   
for incrm in range(1,nincr+1):
    f     = f + fincr                     
    resid = resid - fincr                 

rnorm = cnorm*2                             
niter = 0
while ((rnorm > cnorm) and (niter < miter)):
    niter = niter+1
    u    = resid/stiff
    x    = x+u
    l    = ma.sqrt(x*x + d*d)
    area = vol/l
    stress = e*ma.log(l/lzero)
    t      = stress*area*x/l
    resid  = t-f
    rnorm  = abs(resid/f)
    stiff = (area/l)*(e-2*stress)*(x/l)*(x/l) + (stress*area/l)

    print(niter)
    print(rnorm)
```

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず動くコードだとこんな感じです。`rnorm[-1]`は`rnorm`の一番最後の要素を取り出します。変更した後半だけ書いておきます。

```
rnorm = [cnorm*2]                             
niter = [0]
while ((rnorm[-1] > cnorm) and (niter[-1] < miter)):
    niter.append(niter[-1]+1)
    u    = resid/stiff
    x    = x+u
    l    = ma.sqrt(x*x + d*d)
    area = vol/l
    stress = e*ma.log(l/lzero)
    t      = stress*area*x/l
    resid  = t-f
    rnorm.append(abs(resid/f))
    stiff = (area/l)*(e-2*stress)*(x/l)*(x/l) + (stress*area/l)

print(niter)
print(rnorm)
```